# approximation of a Gaussian Summation

Tags: summation, gaussian

Is there a way to approximate this summation
$$\sum_{x=1}^{n}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x}{\delta n }\right)^{2}}$$

Thanks

Comment: If $\delta>0$ is fixed, then we have $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x}{\delta n})^2} \sim n\int_{0}^{1}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2\delta^2}}\,\mathrm{d}t $$ as $n\to\infty$. In fact, the difference of both sides is bounded by a constant that depends only on $\delta$.

Comment: Thank you,  does the integral tend towards a constant expressed with $\delta$